# Min and max eigenvalues of a quadratic form

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

I have the following quadratic form :
$q(x,y,z)=x(y+4z)+y(x-2z)+x^2$, represented by the symmetric matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&2\\1&0&-1\\2&-1&0\end{bmatrix}$.
I am asked to find its signature, which appears to be $(2,1)$. And then, I am asked to prove that all of its matrix's eigenvalues are in $]-3,3[$ without computing them. I can't see how to do this.

Comment: "...appears to be"? Can't you just calculate it? And what does "computing them" (the eigenvalues) mean? Without finding them explicitly but with the char. pol. it looks like a more or less easy exercise in Calculus I, IVT and etc.

Comment: Use [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem)

Comment: @YadatiKiran Gershgorin's Theorem doesn't give so tight a bound for the eigenvalues of the matrix. As far as I can see it only gives $\;(-3,4)\;$...

Comment: The bound is $(-2,4)$. We get three discs $D(1,3), D(0,2)$ and $D(0,3)$

Comment: We can also say $\sum|\lambda-a_{ii}|\leq\sum R_i \implies |\lambda-1|+|\lambda|+|\lambda|\leq8 \implies \dfrac{-7}{3}\leq\lambda\leq3$